# PhoneGap PlugIn not working

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying the PhoneGap Plugin for Android app in my code.My HTML Strict 4 Code is as follows

**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="system.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var uname;

function validate(){    

    //uname = document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
    //var pass = document.forms[0].elements[1].value;

    uname=document.getElementById("i1").value;
    var pass=document.getElementById("i2").value;

    alert("Uname: "+uname+"\r\nPass: "+pass);

    if(!uname || uname === "" || !pass || pass === ""){

        alert("User Credentials are incorrect");

    }
    else{           

        //Make a webservice call
          post_data(uname,pass,postDataCB);     


    }

}

function postDataCB(retval){

    alert("In postDataCB()\r\nuname: "+uname);

}



</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form>
      User name: <input type="text" id="i1" name="username" value="GEO02-OTPUAT" /><br />
      Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" id="i2" name="pwd" value="aaa111" /><br />
      <button onclick="javascript:validate()">Submit</button><br />
  </form>
```

In My HTML, I have a Global Variable called `uname`. This variable is used in the callback function `postDataCB()`, But it comes as undefined. (I did alert and saw)
What I observed was when i remove the `<form />`  element from HTML Code, it seems to work.

So can any one plz tell me why it is happening and how to solve this issue.

**CODE of post_data:**

```
public PluginResult post_data(JSONArray funcargs, String jscallbackid){

    SuccessCallBack=funcargs.getString(0);
    FailureCallBack=funcargs.getString(1);
        uname= funcargs.getString(2);
    passw = funcargs.getString(3);      


    conn = new URL("http://www.subratlogin.com/login").openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);


    data += URLEncoder.encode(uname, "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(passw, "UTF-8") + "&";

    //remove the unwanted & at the end of the string
    data = data.substring(0,data.length()-1);  

    ro = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    ro.write(data);

    //Close the connection
    ro.close(); 

    try{

        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
           sb.append(line);
        }

    //Close the connection
       rd.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        SendJS = "javascript:" + FailureCallBack + "('" + e.getMessage() + "')"; 
        sendJavascript(SendJS);
        return null;
    }

    SendJS = "javascript:" + SuccessCallBack + "('" + JSONObject.quote(sb.toString()); 

    if(jObj != null)
        SendJS += "','" +  jObj + "')";
    else if(StringParam != null)
        SendJS += "','" + StringParam + "')";
    else
        SendJS += "')";

    sendJavascript(SendJS);
    return null;    
 }
```

sry fr asking this type of question.

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE. This is not an Eclipse Problem to tag Eclipse.
Shouldn't you be tagging `phonegap-plugins` instead ?

Comment: Holy cowwww!!! People still use phonegap 1.0.0 :O

Comment: I am suffering from a similar issue please go through my thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451155/phonegap-plugin-behaving-in-a-strange-manner

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not following the plugin spec at all and I don't see any place where you setup a listener for deviceready.

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android

Comment: Please read my comment above. From his description it seems his Phonegap Plugin is working correctly

Comment: @nimish as one of the core PhoneGap Android committers I can say that the user is going about this the wrong way. They'd have better results if they followed the proscribed way to write a plugin.

Comment: I will also try to figure this out Hope i am successful at it :)